# What is causing "junk after end of expression" error from xpath command?

Tags: xml, xpath, syntax-error

Being far short of expert at XML, I've been going through basic tutorials.  There is [this one](http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xpathattribute.php) on xpath.   Luckily, my Linux setup has an 'xpath' command which works fine, until I get to attributes.

```
xpath -e 'inventory/snack/chips@supplier'  lemonade2.xml
```

gives the error

```
Parse of expression inventory/snack/chips@supplier failed - junk after end of expression: @supplier at /usr/share/perl5/XML/XPath/Parser.pm line 127.
```

My lemonade2.xml is copy-pasted straight from the site. xpath works fine without the '@supplier'.

Maybe there's some subtle missing character or something, or I've fat-fingered xpath into ruin somehow.  Maybe the tutorial is very old and uses obsolete xpath syntax? Nah, that would break a lot of existing code, wouldn't it?  Could it be interference with bash syntax?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing attributes is a path step in XPath, you're missing the slash in front of the attribute.

```
xpath -e 'inventory/snack/chips/@supplier'  lemonade2.xml
```

Is `<inventory/>` the outermost element? Then you might also want to declare the root in front of it:

```
xpath -e '/inventory/snack/chips@supplier'  lemonade2.xml
```

Comment: It seems to work fine without the initial root slash, but the slash before the '@' solves the problem.  Funny, the writer of that tutorial doesn't have it.

Comment: This is definitely no XPath, better choose another tutorial writer next time. :)

Comment: It's a pretty basic error, I would avoid this tutorial in future. Remember that the internet is a great source of free information but an awful lot of it is wrong.